# Iam using bootstrap-multiselect.js for dropdown select options, i need to select checkboxes for a certain limit..?

Tags: javascript, html

Iam using below javascript to limit the check boxes.

```
function tdClick(value){
var no = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
    if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= no) {
        this.checked = false;
    }
});
```

But i am not able to figure out the select ids in the code. The bootstrap-multiselect.js is internally listing out the options. can anyone help me with this..?

Answer (score 0):

use this `$("#selector-id :selected").length;` to get the length of selected options

```js
function tdClick(value){
var no = 3;
$("#selector_id").on("change", function () {
    
    var count = $("#selector_id :selected").length;
    
    if(count>3){
      // your logic
    }
    
});
```